# Can I save multiple cards for one shopper using the BlueSnap Payment API?

Tags: bluesnap

I'm vaulting credit card data on BlueSnap, using the vaulted shopper request.How can I vault multiple cards for the same shopper? Will it return a single token or different tokens per card?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BlueSnap vaults cards under a shopper and supports multiple cards per shopper. Here’s an example of how to vault a Shopper with two credit cards:

```
<vaulted-shopper xmlns="http://ws.plimus.com">
   <first-name>FirstName</first-name>
   <last-name>LastName</last-name>
   <payment-sources>
      <credit-card-info>
         <credit-card>
            <card-number>4263982640269299</card-number>
            <security-code>837</security-code>
            <expiration-month>02</expiration-month>
            <expiration-year>2018</expiration-year>
         </credit-card>
      </credit-card-info>
      <credit-card-info>
         <credit-card>
            <card-number>374245455400126</card-number>
            <security-code>1234</security-code>
            <expiration-month>05</expiration-month>
            <expiration-year>2017</expiration-year>
         </credit-card>
      </credit-card-info>
   </payment-sources>
</vaulted-shopper>
```

Notice in the code above that the `credit-card-info` element has 2 `credit-card` elements. When using this vaulted shopper to conduct transactions you will need to pass the `card-last-four-digits` and `card-type` to tell BlueSnap which card to use for the specific transaction.